# Consider the sequence defined: $a_1 = 1/3, a_{n+1} = a_n + 1/(2^{n+1}+n+1)$, show that is bounded above and increasing using induction.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried that but it didn't work out for me...

for $n=1$, I said that $1/3 \le a_1 = 1/3 \le 1$
so I assumed that for $n$, $1/3 \le a_n \le$ and I tried to prove for $a_{n+1}$ but I couldn't get it to work...

Comment: Please use Latex correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}>0 \forall n\in \Bbb N$

Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence.

For bound, see $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}+n+1}<\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$

Therefore, $$a_{n+1}<a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}<a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}<\cdots<\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^{2}}+\frac{1}{2^{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}<1$$

Answer (score 1):

If you are expected to do a **formal** induction argument, then you can modify Avatar's answer as follows.

Lemma: $a_n \lt 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Proof: The result holds when $n=1$. Suppose it holds for a particular integer $k$. Then
$$a_{k+1} = a_k+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}+k+1}\lt a_k+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\lt 1-\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=1-\left(\frac{1}{2^k}-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right).$$
But $\frac{1}{2^k}- \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$, so the induction step is complete.

**Remark:** In general, if $b$ is a **constant**, we will not be able to use the induction hypothesis $a_k \lt b$ to prove that $a_{k+1}\lt b$. This is because if we are adding something positive to $a_k$ to get $a_{k_1}$, the fact that $a_k\lt b$ is not **by itself** enough to show that $a_{k+1}\lt b$.

Our induction hypothesis has to be *stronger* than $a_k\lt b$. Something like the $a_k\lt b-f(k)$ that we used above often works.

Comment: In your lemma, you are missing a negative sign in the exponent.